# How can I check if RMI is connected/can be connected?

Tags: java, rmi

I want to know if my RMI port is available or if busy. While I know that an exception will be thrown if it cannot connect, I would like to have that under control - to show a message "Connection Failed" and stop the process. (I am working with Eclipse). How can that be done?

Comment: I do not really get what you want to do. Is this some kind of Eclipse plugin? What do you mean by "my RMI port is busy"?
Please elaborate, preferrably with some sample code.

Comment: @DanielSchneller you don't know [Java RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html)?

Comment: Define 'my RMI port', 'available or busy', 'it', 'have that under control'. Question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you cannot control ports, its sort of a first come first served. If you want to listen at a port say 3306, just try and open a server socket on it, if the process of binding fails its because its already in use.

RMI runs at a specific port, and so perhaps your question is about client side sockets in which case you only need to make sure that the RMI service is running?

Assuming u want to find out if RMI is running, u cud try establishing an RMI service at that port, if it fails because of a "Refused to connect" Exception, then RMI is not running

Comment: Are you saying that's the only way to know whether the registry is up?? Can't you do something better than deciding only when an exception is thrown?

Comment: @Anubis Define 'better'. Java throws `ConnectExceptions`. That is the defined mechanism.